# Will fread ever stop reading so another process can continue?

Tags: c, pipe, exec, posix, stdio

In my main function I call fork 3 times ( always in the parent process). The child processes communicate using anonymous pipes and run other programs with `execlp`.If one program starts writing some data to the writing end of a pipe after I run `dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)`(the program thinks it writes to stdout) and read it on the other end of the pipe using fread (program run by exec is reading from stdin but I have used `dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO)` before running `execlp` to read from the pipe) is it possible that the fread function will stop reading halfway through? Same can be asked for the write system call I use when writing - is it possible it will stop writing halfway through ?

**EDIT**

Some clarification on how the program is run:

```
    pipe(fd);

    p2 = fork();

    if (p2 > 0)
        p3=fork();

    if (p2==0){
       dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
       //close all file descriptors here
       execlp("./p2","p2",NULL);
       /*program that prints to stdout after taking stdin input
       like this : write(STDOUT_FILENO,stuff,stuff_size*/
    }
    if (p3==0){
       dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
       //close all file descriptors here
       execlp("./p3","p3",NULL);/*program that takes stdin input
       like this :fread(foo,sizeof(foo_t),1,stdin);*/
    }
```

The question:
Is there a chance my fread functions will stop reading halfway through and the p3 process will go to the background before all the data is read ?

Comment: More code, please!

Comment: @RSahu I edited my original post to make it a bit more clear w/ some code

Comment: You need to call `pipe` in parent for each of your child processes. They [effectively] can't share the single pipe too well. If you're trying to set up the equivalent of the shell command: `p1 | p2 | p3 | p4` you'd need 3 `pipe` calls.

Comment: Also, it's important that a child process closes the fd for the ends of the pipes it _doesn't_ use (e.g. when reading, it should close `fd[1]`). And the parent and child need to be careful to not keep open pipes that "belong" to other child processes. (i.e.) In my example, a given child should have two pipes: an input pipe and an output pipe and only use `pipein_fd[0]` for input and `pipeout_fd[1]` for output. Everything else should be cleaned up/closed before doing the `execlp`